# create simple dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

> person1    wine2
>
> person1    wine1
>
> person2    wine1
>
> person2    wine2
>
> person2    wine3
>
> person2    wine4
>
> person2    wine5

The above is my input in a separate text file. I want to create the following output dictionary in Python:

> output = {'wine1': ['person1', 'person2'], 'wine2':['person1','person2'], 'wine3':['person2'], 'wine4':['person2'], 'wine5':['person2'] }

How do I create this output?

I'm doing something wrong:

```
def read(text): 
    wine_wishes = dict() 
    final_assignments = dict()
    with open(text) as infile:
        for line in infile: 
            line = line.split() 
            try: 
                wine_wishes[line[1]]
            except: 
                wine_wishes[line[1]] = [line[0]]
```

As a result I get the incorrect output: {'wine4': ['person2'], 'wine5': ['person2'], 'wine1': ['person1'], 'wine2': ['person1'], 'wine3': ['person2']}

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in infile:
    if line.strip(): # skip blank lines
        person, wine = line.split()
        d[wine].append(person)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(dict(d))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/4o9ygv)

```
{'wine1': ['person1', 'person2'],
 'wine2': ['person1', 'person2'],
 'wine3': ['person2'],
 'wine4': ['person2'],
 'wine5': ['person2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each value in the dict be a list, *and append entries after the first for each key to the list already in the dictionary*.

```
def read(text): 
    wine_wishes = dict() 

    with open(text) as infile:
        for line in infile: 
            line = line.split()
            if line[1] not in wine_wishes:
                wine_wishes[line[1]] = []

            wine_wishes[line[1]].append(line[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

As J.F. Sebastian mentioned, `collections.defaultdict` can be used to accomplish

> D.get(k,d) and set D[k]=d if k not in D

But there a method `setdefault` for `dict`, which has the same effect.

```
    for line in infile: 
        line = line.split()
        wine_wishes.setdefault(line[1], []).append(line[0])
```

EDIT: It's not related to this question. I just found `split` is nut fully understood.

> split(...)
>
> > S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
> >
> > Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
> >        delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
> >        splits are done. **If sep is not specified or is None, any
> >        whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
> >        from the result**.

Therefore, we don't need to use `strip` to remove the leading and trailing whitespaces or pass a whitespace delimiter to `split`. `line.split()` is enough.

Comment: `line.split()` returns an empty list for a blank line. You need to skip blank lines to avoid IndexError.